# is there a way to "associate" Actions with Armatures?

Tags: animation

i have several slightly different armatures (copies of the original one with rescaled or added bones) and numerous actions. some actions are supposed to be shared, some will be used by only one of the armatures. is there a way to sort of associate certain actions with certain armatures to make it easier to find out which armature supposed to use which action? armatures will be exported, not used inside Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out it can be seen in Outliner - animations are listed as armature's children!